# find path for each element

Tags: ruby, recursion, path

Given a list i want to find the path of each interconnected elements as given in the question.

```
mapping = {
  "a"=>["b"], 
  "sub"=>["sub1"], 
  "sub1"=>[], 
  "sub2"=>[], 
  "b"=>["c"], 
  "c"=>["d"], 
  "d"=>["e"], 
  "e"=>[], 
  "con"=>["my", "a", "mex1"], 
  "my"=>[], 
  "mex1"=>[], 
  "max"=>[]
}
```

How can i find path of each element as :-

```
      a : root->con->a
      b : root->con->a->b
      c : root->con->a->b->c
      d : root->con->a->b->c->d
      e : root->con->a->b->c->d->e
      sub : root->sub
      sub1 : root->sub->sub1
      sub2 : root->sub2
      con : root->con
      my : root->con->my
      mex1 : root->con->mex1
      max : root->max
```

**This code giving wrong output**

```
def get_hier mapping,lst,count,path
  lst.each do |item|
    if (count >25)
        puts "Deep hierarchy, possible cases of circular dependency, last detected hierarchy # 
 {item}"
    break
  end
  if(mapping[item]!=[] and mapping.key?(item))
    if (count == 1)
      # puts "INFO : Processing second hier #{item}"
    end
    path=path+"->"+item
    get_hier(mapping,mapping[item],count+1,path)
    add_rows(item,path)
  else
    if(mapping[item]==[] and mapping.key?(item))
      y=path
      y=y+"->"+item
      add_rows(item,y)
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me out getting this.

Comment: So to be clear `{"a"=>["b"], "sub"=>["sub1"], "sub1"=>[], "sub2"=>[], "b"=>["c"], "c"=>["d"], "d"=>["e"], "e"=>[], "con"=>["my", "a", "mex1"], "my"=>[], "mex1"=>[], "max"=>[]}` is your input? Are we supposed to output all trees or will you be providing a target?

Comment: In formatting your code I found two extra `end` statements at the end, which I removed.

Comment: for all elements of trees @engineersmnky

Comment: If your comment above was meant for engineersmnky your should include @engineersmnky in the comment so that he will be notified by SO that a comment has been left for him.

Comment: Still giving wrong path @engineersmnky

Comment: This is going to need some additional explanation for example to get to "e". It can be `"root->con->a->b->c->d->e"` as you show but why can't it be any of `"root->a->b->c->d->e"`, `"root->b->c->d->e"`, ..., `"root->e"`?

Comment: We want the longest hierarchical path. It's like hierarchy @engineersmnky

Answer (score 0):

you can try below

```
output_hash = {}
mapping.keys.each do |key, value|
  output_hash[key] = "root->"
  subpath = key
  parent = mapping.select{|k,v| k if v.include?(key)}
  while parent.any?
    subpath = "#{parent.keys.last}->#{subpath}"
    parent = mapping.select{|k,v| k if v.include?(parent.keys.last)
  end
  output_hash[key] += subpath.to_s
end
```

This will produce the below output

```
$> output_hash
=> {"a"=>"root->con->a",
 "sub"=>"root->sub",
 "sub1"=>"root->sub->sub1",
 "sub2"=>"root->sub2",
 "b"=>"root->con->a->b",
 "c"=>"root->con->a->b->c",
 "d"=>"root->con->a->b->c->d",
 "e"=>"root->con->a->b->c->d->e",
 "con"=>"root->con",
 "my"=>"root->con->my",
 "mex1"=>"root->con->mex1",
 "max"=>"root->max"}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: `present?` is a rails method consider changing this to `until parent.empty?` or `while parent.any?`

Comment: yup, @engineersmnky. updated in the answer.

Comment: @AmolMohite if we have repeated variables like "e" comes 2 time say "b"=> ["c","e"] and "d"=["e"] output will will contain both the paths of e. like e : root->con->a->b->c->d->e and e : root->con->a->b->e can you help me in this.

Comment: Since `output_hash` is a hash,  I have only   `e: root->con->a->b->c->d->` this value in it.
so as per my understanding you want both paths in output, right?